# How can I remove the border of expansion panel in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

How can I remove the border of expansion panel area in Material-UI?

Answer (score 21):

You should be able to set the elevation to 0 which will remove the box-shadow:

`<Accordion elevation={0}>`

(note: ExpansionPanel has been renamed to Accordion)

Answer (score 10):

This works for version "**@material-ui/core": "4.9.9**"

You can use the following to be applied for the entire theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanel: {
      root: {
        '&:before': {
          display: 'none'
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Or if you need it only for one component then can be hidden through a class style:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

....
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  hideBorder: {
    '&.MuiExpansionPanel-root:before': {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
})

....
const classes = useStyles()

.....
<ExpansionPanel className={classes.hideBorder}>
```

Comment: you should be worshipped

Answer (score 5):

Try to edit the css of the `expansion-panel` class (I guess you mean the box shadow, there is no border)

```
.expansion-panel {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: To get both the top border and the shadow eliminated, I had to combine Victor and Raul's answers. The styling object ends up looking like this: const useStyles = makeStyles({
  hideBorder: {
    boxShadow: 'none',
    '&.MuiExpansionPanel-root:before': {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
})

Comment: @Sumiya Sayeed Did that do it for you ?

Answer (score 3):

In mui 5.11 following worked for me :

<Accordion elevation={0} sx={{ '&:before':{height:'0px'}}}>

Answer (score 2):

This works for **@mui/material 5.1.0**:

```js
MuiAccordion: {
 styleOverrides: {
  root: {
    "&:before": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
  },
 },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me `@mui/material: ^5.8.7`

I create style like this

```
const AccordionStyle = {
  '&:before': {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
  },
};
```

and I used the style in sx

```
<Accordion sx={AccordionStyle}>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `@mui/material: ^5.11.12`

Give `mat-expansion-panel` a class of `mat-elevation-z0`

Might need to tweak your background colors, but it at least removes the border shadow

```
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                   (closed)="panelOpenState = false">

   <mat-expansion-panel-header>

     <mat-panel-title>
       <span class="right">Filter</span>
     </mat-panel-title>

   </mat-expansion-panel-header>

   <p><app-data></app-data></p>

 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
border: 'none'
```

This helped me.