# Remove shadows from material-ui accordion

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react js project and i want to remove the shadows or border from the accordion component.
[image: The displayed accordion]

Comment: Refer to this, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004930/how-can-i-remove-the-border-of-expansion-panel-in-material-ui

Comment: i tried it and it didn't help

Answer (score 8):

passing a style to your component

```
style={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
```